# Weinre and Phonegap Developer App

Tags: cordova, weinre

Has someone managed to debug Phonegap applications remotely with Weinre and Phonegap Developer App?

I can connect to

```
http://192.168.1.100:8001/client
```

from both sites but don't see the target.

```
<script src="http://192.168.1.100:8001/target/target-script-min.js"></script>
```

is in index.html.

In my case Weinre is running on port 8001 and Phonegap Developer App on port 8000 on the same network.

I'm wondering whether this can work at all?

Comment: Is `boundHost` the actual value? If so, try replacing that with `192.168.1.100`

Comment: no, 192.168.1.100 is in the script src. Has been edited.

Comment: have you set `<access origin="*" />` in your config?

Comment: It was set to something else, but this solved my issue. Thanks so much!!